# django-admin-tools : change header 'Django Administration'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using `django-admin-tool` to customized my django admin page. my problem is, how can I change the header of 'Django Administration' with django-admin-tools?

i know how to change it using `base_site.html` but the problem is my `custom menu` that i have done in `django-admin-tools` is not appearing.

Comment: Try looking here https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/src/522004b1d118/admin_tools/theming/templates/admin/base.html I guess {% block branding %}{% endblock %} is inherited somewhere

Comment: thanks for the reply ilvar, i try to insert my title in `{% block branding %}My Administration{% endblock %}` but it wont work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `django-admin-tools` header is controlled by the theming.css file which is by default sitting under **\admin_tools\theming\static\admin_tools\css\theming.css**, and the default header should display the "Django" png that comes with `django-admin-tools` and is placed under **\admin_tools\theming\static\admin_tools\images\django.png**.

I guess that if the default admin tools header doesn't display then your admin tools theme is not kicking in either. This means django can't see your theming folder of admin tools. Check that your `MEDIA_ROOT`, `STATIS_ROOT` and`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` parameters in setting.py are set correctly. Check the PYTHONPATH env param is also set to all the needed folders.

When the default admin tools theme will load you can drop a new header image in the images folders as above and edit the theming.css to load it instead of the default.